# What is the end-point of material from an apoptotic cell, after phagocytosis?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, immune-system

Apoptosis occurs. The organelles and interior material form apoptotic bodies that are packed in vesicles. The cell membrane breaks apart (cell no longer exists) and apoptotic bodies enter the extracellular space. Phagocytes "eat" the apoptotic bodies.

What happens then?

Is the material processed again and effluxed into the blood, sent to other cells, ...?